# Multi-server Ruby on Rails Production Logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, production-environment, multiple-instances

I currently have an RoR app in production across four application servers with independent logs per instance.  What's the best way to aggregate the logging to a common location without resorting to syslog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if there is a flavor of log4xxx for ruby.. Could be real cool. If there is, then perhaps you could centralize the streams from different instances into one place, it shouldn't be too complicated for simple implementation.., or perhaps use a tool [like this](http://www.logfaces.com).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  There's a log4r that might work for collection.